# xaml asking for easy way

Tags: c#, wpf

there is any way to not use rowdefinition 
like all the thing  set one after other one
like html

```
   <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="auto"  Width="300" Background="#FF343434" x:Name="new_order">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Order:Table 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" Margin="5" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="set in 10:00" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="16" Margin="3"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _all the thing set one after other_?

Comment: like html <table>
<tr></tr><tr></tr></table>

Comment: can you give link or example about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [StackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx):

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Row 1" />
    <TextBlock Text="Row 2" />
    <TextBlock Text="Row 3" />
</StackPanel>
```